# Reducing dimensions on each iteration

Tags: javascript

I got this thing over here:

```js
function duplicateElement() {

  const holder = document.querySelector('.holder');
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  let firstEl = elements[0];
  //let lastEl = elements[elements.length - 1];

  console.log(elements.length);

  let dimensions = firstEl.offsetWidth;
  let reducedDimensions = dimensions / 1.45;

  elements.forEach(element => {
    let duplicate = element.cloneNode(true);
    holder.appendChild(duplicate);
    element.style.width = `${reducedDimensions}px`;
    element.style.height = `${reducedDimensions}px`;
  });
}

let callCount = 1;
let repeater = setInterval(function() {
  if (callCount < 5) {
    duplicateElement();
    callCount += 1;
  } else {

    clearInterval(repeater);
  }
}, 5000);
```

```css
.bg-black {
  background: black;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.square::after content: "";
display: block;
padding-bottom: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="bg-black square item"></div>
</div>
```

What this does is that it runs the function `duplicateElements` n times.

In `duplicateElements()` i double the number of elements in each iteration. The parent starts with just 1 item, which become 2, 4, 8, 16, etc (depending on `callCount`). This works as i want.

Additionally, i want to reduce the size of every element. So i check for the dimensions of the first item, divide the number by a factor and apply the new dimensions as width and height to every item.

That however does not work, as it applies the new dimensions only to the newly duplicated items, leaving the items created in the previous iteration with their old values. (You can check this in the console, as it applies that values as well)

What i am missing here? My train of thought was that since i check for all items with `let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item')` anew in EVERY ITERATION, i would also apply my new dimensions to each element.

`console.log(elements.length);` gives me the correct number of items in each iteration so why don't the dimensions apply?

Hey, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is**: you select all elements before the loop in 
`let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item');`

 Which is correct, but then inside the loop you duplicate the current element and append it to the DOM *before* setting the dimensions, so this duplicated element is not getting the new dimensions before beign appended...

So, **the solution is**: just move the part that duplicate the element to below the part that set the dimensions, see below, inside the loop 
(I reduced to 1 second to faster example)

```js
function duplicateElement() {

  const holder = document.querySelector('.holder');
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  let firstEl = elements[0];
  console.clear()
  console.log(elements.length);

  let dimensions = firstEl.offsetWidth;
  let reducedDimensions = dimensions / 1.45;

  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.style.width = `${reducedDimensions}px`;
    element.style.height = `${reducedDimensions}px`;
    let duplicate = element.cloneNode(true);
    holder.appendChild(duplicate);
  });
}

let callCount = 1;
let repeater = setInterval(function() {
  if (callCount < 5) {
    duplicateElement();
    callCount += 1;
  } else {

    clearInterval(repeater);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.bg-black {
  background: black;
}

.item {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.square::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="bg-black square item"></div>
</div>
```

Also, I fixed the CSS, there was missing a `{`

Comment: Facepalm (once again). Thanks Calvin, you are correct